# Inequality Filter in AppEngine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I understand that Google AppEngine supports only one inequality filter per query. What are the workaround on this limitation? Are there any solution that will provide similar effect?

Answer (score 3):

Actually GAE supports multiple inequality filters as long as they are [on the same property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Restrictions_on_Queries).

The workarounds to this limitation are data-specific, e.g. it depends how your data is structured and how you want to query it. For example, for geo searching, as @Dan Holevoet mentioned, there are various geo-hashing algorithms. 
Basically all such algorithms involve combining multiple properties into one and at the same time quantizing the property (creating discrete values). For example geo-hashing involves dividing up the world map into small fixed-size areas (= combining lat/lon and quantizing) in order to be able to search via equality operator.

Answer (score 1):

Whether there is a workaround for having a single inequality filter per query depends on the type of dataset you are querying over.

For instance, if you wanted to query positional data using a latitude and longitude address, you'd typically need to query for a range of values on two properties (lat and long). However, with a [geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) algorithm you can accomplish an equivalent query using only a single property.

Answer (score 0):

When I meat this problem (example searching range from - to) I use query with single inequality filter. Depending on sorting order (asc or desc) I select upper or bottom limit. After that I filter result programatically with bottom or upper limit that was not in query filter.

Comment: was it necessary? as mentioned by Peter, multiple inequality filters is supported as long as they are on the same property.

Comment: I try to use one (range from - to) for same date field - it was not supported for me. I use it with JDO